# custom Background not showing after upgrade?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I've been using wp3 custom background feature. Today I updated to the latest version and now my custom background isn't showing. Strange thing is Appearance > Background still shows the custom background I'm using. Has anyone seen this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](http://www.wpexplorer.com/blog/custom-background-not-working-in-wordpress-3-3.html) helped me solve my issue.

Changing `<body>` in header.php to

```
<body <?php body_class(''); ?>>
```